# XMPP chat user returning null

Tags: ios, chat, xmppframework

I am implementing iPhone chat app using XMPP. I am trying to get user object by using following code:

```
       [[self appDelegate].xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
       [self appDelegate].xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;
       [self appDelegate].xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;
       [[self appDelegate].xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
       [[self appDelegate].xmppRoster fetchRoster];
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self appDelegate].xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"user@ip" ] xmppStream:[self appDelegate].xmppStream  managedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster]];
```

But it is returning null user object.

I am getting list of users in tableview controller and it is working fine. but in another view where I am trying to get perticular user it is giving an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have added following method :

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
}
```

And tried to get the user details there and it is working now.

Comment: Where do I need to add this method?

Comment: Please add it in the viewController. Please call your getting user data function through this function.

Comment: If you did't get what you want please share your code.